# RegEx for cleanup a string

Tags: php, regex, validation

This RegEx is for cleanup user input from a search form

```
$query = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 _.,*&-]/", ' ', $query);
```

I need to add the slash as a valid character too, but if I add it, I get an error. I assume I have to escape it but can't find how to do that

```
$query = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 _.,*&-/]/", ' ', $query); // doesn't works
$query = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 _.,*&-//]/", ' ', $query); // doesn't works
$query = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 _.,*&-\/]/", ' ', $query); // doesn't works
```

Using php

Comment: With php-5.1.6 at least, your last example (...\/]/") runs happily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something other then the `/` as your delimiter - try something like this:

```
$query = preg_replace("%[^A-Za-z0-9 _.,*&-/]%", ' ', $query);
```

Kobe also posted the correct way to escape in that situation, but I find the regex stays more readable when I switch the delimiter to something I'm not using in the expression, when possible.

**EDIT**

A bit of additional information can be found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php (quoting it here:)

"When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character."

Comment: I knew it was a dumb questios, but now I feel even dumber. I didn't know you can use other delimiter...

Comment: Agreed - yours is neater. Make sure to move `-` though, you accepting characters **between** `&` and `/`!

Comment: I added some info on using alternate delimiters. % is my personal goto, but I see ~ used a lot, also.

Answer (score 4):

You should escape twice - you need to create the string `"\/"`, so the backslash should also be escape as `"\\/"`:

```
$query = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 _.,*&\\/-]/", ' ', $query);
```

Also, make sure you move `-` to the end, or escape that as well. It has a different between two characters in a character set.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 _.,*&-\/]/", ' ', $query);
```

would work if you wrote it with single quotes, like this:

```
$query = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 _.,*&\/-]/', ' ', $query);
```

The cause of this is that strings enclosed in " are parsed for \n, \r \t etc. and $vars. Thus; escaping a / makes PHP try to find a special meaning for "/" as in "\n" and when it fails it removes the backslash.

Strings enclosed in ' are not parsed.

Answer (score 1):

To escape a character, just put a backslash in front of it ; but don't forget you are using a double-quoted string -- which is probably the reason that makes this harder : you probably have to espace the backslash itself.

Another solution that I generally use is to work with a different regex delimiter, that you don't have in your regex. For instance, using a `#` :

```
$query = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z0-9 _.,*&-/]#", ' ', $query);
```

This should solve the problem :-)